# selected value on regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm having a problem with regular expression to validate user input. For example

```
if(preg_match("/(male|female)/",$gender)==true)
{
    echo "true";
}
```

When the user types anything after "male" or "female" my code still outputs "true". How to solve this problem?

Comment: `"/^(male|female)$/"` will work, or use an array as Jon suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you don't need a regular expression for this. You can use a simple array as a whitelist:

```
if (in_array($gender, ['male', 'female'])) echo "true";
```

As for the regex part, the problem is that you are not using any [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), so your regex matches if `(male|female)` occurs anywhere inside the input. You can force a regex to match the entirety of the input by including the `^` and `$` anchors:

```
if(preg_match("/^(male|female)$/",$gender)) echo "true";
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not it better to do it with

```
if ( $gender == 'male' || $gender == 'female' ) {}
```

or

```
if ( in_array($gender, array('male', 'female')) ) {}
```

?